# Launching youBot driver and simulating the robot

Tags: gazebo, simulation, rviz, simulator-gazebo, youbot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS users,

my intention is to run the simulation of a robot (KUKA youbot), so that I could be able to control the virtual model in rviz. As far as I understood from the Guide, to solve this task one has to launch RVIZ, launch the OODL driver for the robot in parallel and launch the state publisher (youbot_joint_state_publisher). RVIZ can be launched and the state publisher seems to launch properly (though I don't understand what use is made of it; shouldn't it have some GUI??). PROBLEM: can't launch the driver:

youbot@oleksandr-laptop:~$ roscd youbot_oodl/launch

youbot@oleksandr-laptop:~/ros_stacks/youbot-ros-pkg/youbot_drivers/youbot_oodl/launch$ ./start_youbot_oodl_driver

[sudo] password for youbot:

[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named youbot_oodl below /home/youbot/ros_stacks/youbot-ros-pkg/youbot_drivers/youbot_oodl

[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,

[rosrun] or not executable:

[rosrun]   /home/youbot/ros_stacks/youbot-ros-pkg/youbot_drivers/youbot_oodl

In /home/youbot/ros_stacks/youbot-ros-pkg/youbot_drivers/youbot_oodl/launch THERE IS A FILE NAMED start_youbot_oodl_driver..

I will be grateful for any help!!! Hope to get it very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9668/launching-youbot-driver-and-simulating-the-robot/) by [ASMIK2011ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/352/asmik2011ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2011-04-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jsogorb](https://answers.ros.org/users/372/jsogorb/) on 2011-04-10**:
Could you make sure that your "youbot" package directory is in the $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable?

**Comment by [ASMIK2011ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/352/asmik2011ros/) on 2011-04-08**:
As far as I understand, rosmake is used to compile packages, not c++ files... But I tried and got:            youbot@oleksandr-laptop:~/ros_stacks/youbot-ros-pkg/youbot_drivers/youbot_oodl/src$ ls
youbot_oodl.cpp  YouBotOODLWrapper.cpp  YouBotOODLWrapper.h
youbot@oleksandr-laptop:~/ros_stacks/youbot-ros-pkg/youbot_drivers/youbot_oodl/src$ rosmake youbot_oodl.cpp
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['youbot_oodl.cpp']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/youbot/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110408-164436
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['youbot_oodl.cpp'] to:
[]
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['youbot_oodl.cpp']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.

**Comment by [jsogorb](https://answers.ros.org/users/372/jsogorb/) on 2011-04-07**:
Did you try to compile ir with rosmake?

**Comment by [ASMIK2011ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/352/asmik2011ros/) on 2011-04-07**:
...What I actually did, I followed the steps described here: http://youbot-store.com/frameworks/8/software.aspx.. And so, when I come to ./start_youbot_oodl_driver, it says that there is no executable file named youbot_oodl.. But in slightly different folder (/home/youbot/ros_stacks/youbot_drivers/youbot_oodl/src) there is a file youbot_oodl.cpp.. I try to compile it to get an executable, but gcc returns a bunch of errors...gcc youbot_oodl.cpp
In file included from youbot_oodl.cpp:40:
YouBotOODLWrapper.h:44:33: error: geometry_msgs/Twist.h: No such file or directory
YouBotOODLWrapper.h:45:38: error: tf/transform_broadcaster.h: No such file or directory
YouBotOODLWrapper.h:46:31: error: nav_msgs/Odometry.h: No such file or directory
YouBotOODLWrapper.h:48:45: error: trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory.h: No such file or directory
.... u.s.w.

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-04-06**:
which repo are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all I have no experience with youbot package but i think you should try to run the nodes you need like this:

```
$roscore
$roslaunch package_name executable_name
```

for example: (I'm not sure about the package or executable names as I don't have installed youbot stack)

```
$roslaunch youbot_oodl start_youbot_oodl_driver 
$roslaunch rviz rviz
$roslaunch youbot_oodl youbot_joint_state_publisher
```

---

Originally posted by [jsogorb](https://answers.ros.org/users/372/jsogorb/) with karma: 77 on 2011-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jsogorb](https://answers.ros.org/users/372/jsogorb/) on 2011-04-10**:
The problem with gazobe may be because you don't have it installed in your system. Try to install it form "sudo apt-get install ros-diamontback-gazebo".

**Comment by [jsogorb](https://answers.ros.org/users/372/jsogorb/) on 2011-04-10**:
The problem with gazobe may be because you don't have it installed in your system. Try to install it form "sudo apt-get install ros-diamontback-gazebo".

**Comment by [ASMIK2011ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/352/asmik2011ros/) on 2011-04-08**:
So, how could I try to perform the simulation of the robot and control the rviz robot model? Maybe someone has suggestions? I try to follow the instructions given here http://youbot-store.com/simulation/12/software.aspx. But when I type roslaunch youbot_description youbot_arm_publisher_no_x.launch, I get an ERROR: process[arm_trajectory_republisher-1]: started with pid [3615]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [gazebo/gazebo]: Cannot locate node of type [gazebo] in package [gazebo] AND from gazebo import gazebo_interface
ImportError: No module named gazebo
[youbot_gazebo_model-3] process has died [pid 3616, exit code 1].
log files: /home/youbot/.ros/log/6bd68d42-61f0-11e0-bde2-0013773a743d/youbot_gazebo_model-3*.log

**Comment by [ASMIK2011ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/352/asmik2011ros/) on 2011-04-08**:
Thank you for the answer. But this didn't help. But I found the way to launch the driver: after "compiling the folder" youbot_oodl with rosmake, everything compiled (as it did always before), but this time I noticed the following lines in the end of rosmake logs: [ rosmake ] Summary output to directory;  rosmake ] /home/youbot/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110407-205612 SO I CHANGED THE DIRECTORY TO THIS rosmake output directory  and managed to perform rosrun youbot_oodl youbot_oodl !!! However this returned A NEW ) bunch of exciting errors!! :  Info: Initializing Joints
[FATAL] [1302274632.192262876]: Cannot open youBot driver:
No socket connection on eth0
Excecute as root
[ERROR] [1302274632.192681854]: Base could not be initialized!
Info: Initializing Joints
[FATAL] [1302274632.193422032]: Cannot open youBot driver:
Not enough ethercat slaves were found to create a YouBotManipulator!
[ERROR] [1302274632.193492921]: Arm could not be initialized!